# how to allow users to choose photos only from gallery not from photos app?

Tags: bitmap, image-gallery, picker

> here is my code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setType("image/*");

            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);

            mContext.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), OPEN_GALLERY_REQUEST);
            dismiss();
```

> app crashes if i choose images from photos which are stored in cloud 
>   i fixed the issue by checking the file path if user choose image cloud i toast the message like download image
>
> but is there any way i restrict users to choose image only from gallery 
>   thanks in advance

Comment: image is selected from image picker i have included  the line intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true); to choose only locally stored images but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PHOTO_PICKER_ID);
```

Comment: tried this but it still shows photos and gallery .... i want users to choose images only from gallery not the googles photos app